# vue-cli doesn't create folder structure

Tags: vue.js, structure, project, vue-cli

I am running vue 3.5.1 on Ubuntu.

After installing the newest version via:
`npm install -g @vue/cli`

and then creating a project with: 
`vue create appname`,

vue creates only two files inside the project folder: `package.json` & `package-lock.json`

There is no `src` and `config` with all their components etc. And of course no project can be started without the structure.

How can I create a full vue project folder struce with vue-cli ?

Comment: Small note, you are running Vue CLI 3.51. not vue.
Now, did you run commands with sudo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in my case was to give `NODE_ENV` the right value.

Enter the following command into your terminal:

```
export NODE_ENV=development
```